# Guitar tab - double dash under number

Tags: guitar, tablature

I opened a tab in guitar tab pro on my android phone and there were some sort of double dash (sorry for the lack of a better description), I've never saw that before and I haven't the faintest idea what it is supposed to represent.

Does anyone know what it is?

[image: Dick Dale - Misirlou]

Comment: Possibly a tremolo mark. Nothing to do with wangy bars though!

Comment: @Tim, wangy bars? I am almost afraid to ask what it is.

Comment: Tremolo is rapd repeating of the same note - think mandolin playing. Unfortunately a certain Mr. Fender got his lines crossed, and confused vibrato and tremolo, and called the wangy bars on his Strats tremolos, instead of the (politically!) correct vibratos.

Comment: The term is "whammy bar", not "wangy"!  That's hilarious.

Comment: @MatthewRead - the term is lots of different words, whammy being only one. I just prefer wangy! It's no more or less apposite. Glad you liked it!

Comment: That's a mishearing of the actual word, at best.  It's not commonly used at all.  There are certainly other terms used, like "vibrato bar", though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an indication of a sequence of notes that is meant to be played with the tremolo technique, for electric guitar, the most famous example of this technique is the 'Angel of Death' by Slayer and for the classical guitar the most famous example of the technique is probably 'Recuerdos de la Alhambra' by the Spanish composer Francisco Tarrega.